# Troubles with GNU Radio installation from source

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I'm trying to do a clean installation on a PC running Ubuntu 16.04. Originally, GNU Radio was installed by the build-gnuradio script. However, my new USRP board had a different ABI. I decided to redo the installation. Using the script was pretty smooth the last time I used it. After a very long painful day, I got the build to go as far as 100%  by issuing the command `bash ./build-gnuradio -v -m`. However, there is still an error as shown below

```
    Scanning dependencies of target pyuhd
[ 99%] Building CXX object python/CMakeFiles/pyuhd.dir/pyuhd.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX shared library libpyuhd.so
[100%] Built target pyuhd
Scanning dependencies of target pyuhd_library
[100%] Generating build/timestamp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kiruna/grc/uhd/host/build/python/setup.py", line 9, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup
ImportError: No module named setuptools
python/CMakeFiles/pyuhd_library.dir/build.make:64: recipe for target 'python/build/timestamp' failed
make[2]: *** [python/build/timestamp] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3997: recipe for target 'python/CMakeFiles/pyuhd_library.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [python/CMakeFiles/pyuhd_library.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
UHD build apparently failed
Exiting UHD build
```

I have used the build-gnuradio so many times in the past but things are quite painful now. Any input will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using pybombs. It seems that the issue happens when you have both python2 and python3 installed. In that case, the cmake script in `(UHDSRC)/host/python/CMakeLists.txt` erroneously defaults to python3.

I have fixed the issue by replacing the mention of `${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE}` around line 68 with `${PYTHON2_EXECUTABLE}`

See here: https://twitter.com/f4grx/status/1143620034708815872

Not sure this change is desirable for the upstream project.